# Customer Receiver: Unable to Cast to Device

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I'm having trouble doing a simple "hello-world" with a **Custom Receiver**.

I have really simple sender and receiver apps.

**Sender app:** http://chromecasttest.boxofsoap.com/
**Receiver app:** http://chromecasttest.boxofsoap.com/cast

I've tried casting to my Chromecast device using the Google Cast Beta 
extension for Chrome Canary.

Whenever I visit the sender app URL and try casting to my device, I always 
get a "Unable to cast to device error":
pasteboard.co/1pn6kEel.png

Looking at the console I usually see vague errors like "channel_error" 
or "timeout".

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: I suggest you start with a sample which has a published receiver and make sure that it works for you. Then clone the receiver and use your own app-id for the cloned receiver and make sure that works too. Then switch to your own sender. This way you can make sure that (1) your chromecast is set up correctly for development, (2) your receiver works fine and (3) your sender works fine. If any of these steps fail, you know which part of the picture has an issue to focus on.

Comment: @AliNaddaf - Thanks for the tips! I'm going to try replicating the [CastHelloText-chrome](https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-chrome) example on my server (with my app ID). I'll also try resetting the Chromecast to factory settings and configuring it again.

Comment: you should add you device in cast developer console wait for 15 minutes then you must restart your chrome device to get it in the list of cast receiving devices. thanks

Answer (score 0):

**@AliNaddaf** - Thanks again for your help, after some debugging I found out that the issue was related to the server that was serving the receiver app.

Comment: What was the problem ? and what was the solution? please explain it helps.